# How to reach the information contained in the following tags fileset?

Tags: ant

How to reach the informations contained in the following tags "fileset" ?

In fact, I am looking to use the Ant instruction "copy" on the following refid "files.to.copy":

```
<publication>
    <TARGET_ONE>
        <path id="files.to.copy">
            <fileset dir="lib">
                <filename name="idl.zip"/>
                <filename name="AEX_IDXClient.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="src">
                <filename name="AEX_IDXClientCpp.zip"/>
                <filename name="AEX_IDXClient-src.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>
    </TARGET_ONE>
</publication>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html

Use it like this:

```
<copy todir="...">
    <fileset dir="lib">
            <filename name="idl.zip"/>
            <filename name="AEX_IDXClient.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="src">
            <filename name="AEX_IDXClientCpp.zip"/>
            <filename name="AEX_IDXClient-src.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```